# How many known spells does a level 1 spellslinger with 20 int have at creation?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, spells, character-creation

I'm using PCGen to help me make this character, so I'm unsure if it's correct or not.

Spellslingers get no cantrips, but get detect magic and read magic as level 1 spells at character creation. I'm not sure if these spells count towards the maximum level 1 spells (which PCgen seems to think), or replaces cantrips but doesn't effect known level 1 spells, IE, can I learn 8 spells at character creation (3+5) or just 6?

Answer (score 4):

> ...the spellslinger gains the detect magic and read magic cantrips and places them in his spellbook. **He can cast either of these as 1st-level spells.**

I would assume he gains those two "for free", meaning you can place 8 other spells in the spellbook as normal. However, since you cast them "as 1st-level spells" this means you have to prepare them ahead of time, like normal 1st-level spells.